# Permutations, products, and unit fractions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations, egyptian-fractions

Here's a question motivated by some related MathOverflow questions of [Zhi-Wei Sun](https://mathoverflow.net/users/124654/zhi-wei-sun).

Show that, for any $n \ge 1$, there is a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, i.e., some $\pi \in S_n$, such that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k \cdot \pi(k)} = 1.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\pi(k)=k+1$ except for $\pi(n)=1$. Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k\pi(k)}=\frac1n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{k(k+1)}
=\frac1n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)=1.
$$

Comment: Very quick and clean, thanks.  Writing your permutation in "long form," $(2,3,\ldots,n,1)$ always works.  See a follow-up [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316204/) on MathOverflow that includes data on how many permutations satisfy this sum condition.